# Deep Cloning in Yui3

Tags: jquery, yui3

How does one deep clone an object in YUI3 ? 
In jquery it would be typically done as follows

```
var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, object);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [clone method](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_clone) provided by the oop module.

```
YUI().use("oop", function (Y) {
        var obj = { foo: ["bar", "baz", "biz"] },
        clone = Y.clone(obj, true);
    });
```

Comment: This is only part of the solution. this fails if it's needed to achieve `$.extend(true, {a: 1}, object)`. to do this, use `Y.merge` over it. e.g., `Y.clone(object, true).merge({a: 1})`